# JSON data into Chart in React

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to display JSON data in a grapgh, but something goes wrong and it throws bunch of errors, can somebody explain please?
What should I change? Thank you!
JSON is very simple

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {
  Chart,
  PieSeries,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui';

import info from './data.json'

const data = {
    information: info.users
}


export default class Demo extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data,
    };
  }

  render() {
    // const { data: chartData } = this.state;
    return (
    
      <Paper>
        <Chart
          data={data}
        >
          <PieSeries
            valueField="area"
            argumentField="country"
          />
        </Chart>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the data is present or not,
2. Change line
   const { data: chartData } = this.state;
   to
   const { data } = this.state;
   it is object consise property.